# empty required field didn't prevent the form from being submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Here i have a text editor and a preview button.The job of the preview button is to get content from the editor and and append it in a div and create another button called "submit".I attached a click event to this button button which will submit the form.But problem is if i left any required field empty ,the form is getting submitted anyway.**if i left the title field empty a submit button inside the form element is prevented the form from being submitted,but a outside form submit button submit the form if the required title field remains empty.**

How to prevent this?

```
 <form action='test.php' method='post' id='editorform'>
      <div id='title'>
        <label for='editorTitle' id='foreditorTitle'>Title
             <input type='text' placeholder='Title of the content' id='editorTitle'  autocomplete='off' required>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div id='editordiv'>
            <textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="50" required>
                This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor.
            </textarea>
      </div>
      <div id='preview'>
            <input type='button' id='previewButton' value='preview' >
      </div>
    </form>

    <div id='content' style='width:750px;position:relative;top:50px;'></div>
     <script>

       CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1');

                   $("#previewButton").click( function lol(event){
                   var content=$('#content');
                   content.html('');


       var  el=CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData();                    
                    var html=$.parseHTML(el);

                    content.append(html);

                    $("<input id='sub' type='button' value='submit'/>").appendTo(content);
                    $(document).on('click','#sub',function(){

                          $("#editorform").submit();

                      });

            });

 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Validation is not done automatically when the form is submitted via the `.submit()` method.

In modern browsers you can use the validity API to force validation checking.

```
$(document).on("click", "#sub", function() {
    var form = $("#editorform")[0];
    if (!form.reportValidity || form.reportValidity()) {
        form.submit();
    }
});
```

The `!form.reportValidity` test allows this to work on older browsers, they'll skip the checks.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/a99vuxjn/4/)